# Add a new field to CS-Cart Banner?

Tags: cs-cart

In CS-Cart how would I go about adding an extra field to the Banner?

Specifically, I would like to add a file upload field under the existing image field.

I can add the field HTML to the banner hook `general_content.override.tpl`, but how do I add the new field in the database so it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Search info about block scheme cs-cart. In tpl not right.